# Is it possible to read multiple asyncio Streams concurrently?

Tags: python, select, stream, python-asyncio

I need to read the output of several asyncio tasks running concurrently.

These tasks are actually created using asyncio.create_subprocess_exec().

In the simplest form I would need to print stdout/stderr of a single process while accumulating lines in separate strings.

My current (working) code is:

```
async def run_command(*args, stdin=None, can_fail=False, echo=False):
    """
    Run command asynchronously in subprocess.

    Waits for command completion and returns return code, stdout and stdin

    Example from:
        http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html
    """
    # Create subprocess
    try:
        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            *args,
            stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
        )
    except (FileNotFoundError, OSError):
        if not can_fail:
            log.error("run_command(%s): Error FileNotFound", args)
        return -1, '', 'File "%s" NotFound' % args[0]

    # Status
    log.debug("run_command(%s): pid=%s", args, process.pid)

    # Wait for the subprocess to finish
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate(stdin)

    # Progress
    if process.returncode == 0:
        log.debug("run_command(%s): ok: %s", process.pid, stdout.decode().strip())
    else:
        log.debug("run_command(%s): ko: %s", process.pid, stderr.decode().strip())

    # Result
    result = process.returncode, stdout.decode().strip(), stderr.decode().strip()

    # Return stdout
    return result
```

Problem with this code is I see nothing till process terminates; some of the spawned processes may take several minutes to complete and would print "interesting" info while executing. How can I print (or log) output as soon as it happens while capturing? (I am aware that omitting capture the underlying process would print, but I *also* need the capture)

I tried to do something along the lines:

```
_stdout = ''
while True:
    data = process.stdout.readline()
    if not data:
        break
    print(data)
    _stdout += data.decode()
```

but I have no idea how to extend this to multiple streams (in this case just stdout/stderr, but potentially expanding to multiple programs). Is there something akin to select() call?

Any hint welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something akin to `select()` call?

The answer to this must be yes, as asyncio is wholly built around a call to `select()`. However it's not always obvious how to translate that to a select on the level of streams. The thing to notice is that you shouldn't try to select the stream exactly - instead, start reading on the stream and rely on the ability to select the progress of the coroutines. The equivalent of `select()` would thus be to use `asyncio.wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` to drive the reads in a loop.

An even more elegant alternative is to spawn separate tasks where each does its thing, and just let them run in parallel. The code is easier to understand than with a `select`, boiling down to a single call to [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather), and yet under the hood asyncio performs exactly the kind of `select()` that was requested:

```
import asyncio, sys, io

async def _read_all(stream, echo):
    # helper function to read the whole stream, optionally
    # displaying data as it arrives
    buf = io.BytesIO()  # BytesIO is preferred to +=
    while True:
        chunk = await stream.read(4096)
        if len(chunk) == 0:
            break
        buf.write(chunk)
        if echo:
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(chunk)
    return buf.getvalue()

async def run_command(*args, stdin=None, echo=False):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *args,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
    if stdin is not None:
        process.stdin.write(stdin)
    process.stdin.close()
    stdout, stderr = await asyncio.gather(
        _read_all(process.stdout, echo),
        _read_all(process.stderr, echo)
    )
    return process.returncode, stdout.decode().strip(), stderr.decode().strip()
```

Note that asyncio's `write()` is not a coroutine, it defaults to writing in the background, so we don't need to include the write among the coroutines we `gather()`.